# Python: how to merge and divide two dataframes?

Tags: python, pandas, merge

I have a dataframe `df`  containing the population `p` assigned to some buildings `b`

```
df
    p    b
0  150   3
1  345   7
2  177   4
3  267   2
```

and a dataframe `df1` that associates some other buildings `b1` to the buildings in `df`

```
df1
    b1    b
0   17    3
1   9     7
2   13    7
```

I want to assign to the buildings that have an association in `df1` a population divided the number of buildings. In this way we generate `df2` that assign a population of `150/2=75` to the buildings `3` and `17` and a population of `345/3=115` to the buildings `7,9,13`.

```
df2

    p     b
0  75     3
1  75    17 
2  115    7  
3  115    9
4  115   13
5  177    4
6  267    2
```

Comment: how do you get `150/2=75` or shall we just consider it and hardcode it? or is it `150/3`

Comment: because `b=3` have an association in `df1`. Thus we have two buildings and `b1=17` and `b=3` that have the same population that I want to divide by 2. Similar to the building `b=7` that have a population of `345` in `df` and two associations in `df1`. Thus I want to divide `345`  by 3 for the buildings `b=17` and `b1=9,13`

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, you can try with merging both dfs on `b` then `stack()` and some cleansing, finally group on `p` and transform `count` and divide `p` with that to get divided values on `p`:

```
m=(df.merge(df1,on='b',how='left').set_index('p').stack().reset_index(name='b')
 .drop_duplicates().drop('level_1',1).sort_values('p'))
m.p=m.p/m.groupby('p')['p'].transform('count')

print(m.sort_index())
```

---

```
       p     b
0   75.0   3.0
1   75.0  17.0
2  115.0   7.0
3  115.0   9.0
5  115.0  13.0
6  177.0   4.0
7  267.0   2.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way using `pd.concat`. After that, `fillna` individually `b1` and `p`. Next, `transform` with `mean` and assign filled `b1` to the final dataframe

```
df2 = pd.concat([df, df1], sort=True).sort_values('b')
df2['b1'] = df2.b1.fillna(df2.b)
df2['p'] = df2.p.fillna(0)
df2.groupby('b').p.transform('mean').to_frame().assign(b=df2.b1).reset_index(drop=True)

Out[159]:
       p     b
0  267.0   2.0
1   75.0   3.0
2   75.0  17.0
3  177.0   4.0
4  115.0   7.0
5  115.0   9.0
6  115.0  13.0
```